# jquery in external file doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jquery code and when I load it right into my page it works but when I put it  into an external js file it doesnt work.

My external js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.list').click(function(e)
    {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(".select_menu input").val(value);

        $(".select_menu").show();
        $(".select_menu input").focus();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $('.select_menu, .select_menu input').click(function(e)
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });

    $(".select_menu input").bind('keyup', function(e)
    {
        //var e = $(event.target);
        var q = $(this).val();
        var dataName = $(this).attr('data-name');

        $("#type").val(dataName);

        selectMenu(q,dataName,e);
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $(".select_menu input").focus(function(e)
    {
        //var e = $(event.target);
        var q = $(this).val();
        var dataName = $(this).attr('data-name');

        $("#type").val(dataName);

        selectMenu(q,dataName,e);
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });


    $(document).click(function() {
        $(".select_menu").hide();
    });

});
```

```
<head>
  <title>Mywebsite</title>

   <!-- stylesheets -->
   <link type="text/css" href="../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link type="text/css" href="../css/green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link type="text/css" href="../css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link type="text/css" href="../css/selectMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

    <!-- jQuery - the core -->  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/selectMenu.js"></script>

    <!-- Fancybox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/fancybox.css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Asmselect, deze code wordt gebruikt bij het toevoegen van medewerkers aan een bedrijf -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.asmselect.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.asmselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

Funny thing is that when i put some some self made functions into the file those functions work fine.

Someone an idea?

Comment: Do you have some error into your console? The call to the file is right? The file is in the right position?

Comment: Do you import it **after** jquery ?

Comment: What dystroy says. What does the HTML page header look like?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, I don't get an error in the console. I have placed an alert at the top of the file and that worked.

Comment: @dystroy, Yes I have placed the file after the jquery.

Comment: We don't have enough information. Please show the complete header. Also check the file is received (and received as javascript).

Comment: @dystroy, I updated my post. selectMenu.js is the file.

Comment: please post your complete html source code

Comment: What is possible is that another script imported after your jsmenu.js breaks it (changing the bindings for example). Try putting your script at end of imports.

Comment: @dystroy, unfortunately that's not the problem. I replaced after the other imports but it didnt work.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see anything wrong. I hate to suggest to give a link to the site but I don't see any better option here.

Comment: @dystroy, That's a little bit difficult because i'm using wamp. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK. As last suggestion I suggest you check the received file is the one you want (caching or path problem).

Comment: Thnx but I tried it already and that's not the problem. Strange thing is that when i put a little jquery code from an other external file into this file it worked. This code worked when i load it into the selectMenu.js $(".nav_top ul li:not(.active) a").css({ opacity: 0.7 });

Answer (score 1):

Your files should be included like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="yourExternalScripts.js">  
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: xhtml ? Please upgrade your headers if you want to do modern HTML and be compatible with IE9.

Comment: if you want to use html5 you should declare <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you load the jquery file properly and load your external js file after that.
And as you told your custom method works fine then the javascript of your browser surely activated. 
so, if you load the jquery file properly and load your external js file after that it will surely work